# Laravel Homestead Windows

Tags: windows, laravel, vagrant, homestead

I just migrated my development machine from MacOS to Windows 10 due to increase .NET development along-side PHP development.

I am trying to install Laravel Homestead, the installation went ok, with Virtualbox first then Vagrant.

My issue is when I run `vagrant up`, I get an error when vagrant is trying to reset Network adapters and fails giving the error **"cannot create host-only" adapter**.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled vbox and vagrant multiple times but it always errors out at that specific point.

I narrowed it down to the `homestead.rb` file and commented out where vagrant tries to create ip bound network. Commenting it out allows vagrant to load the box fine, however, after `ssh(ing)` into the box, I grab the IP from `"ifconfig"` and put that in my host machine's hosts file, but trying to access the desired domain does not work.

I am running Virtual Box 5.2.6 and Vagrant 2.0.2 on a Windows 10 Home device with a 7th gen dual core i7.

- I checked and ensured Virtualization is enabled in the BIOS.

Any ideas on how I can get Laravel Homestead running properly on Windows 10?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are running `vagrant` commands from an elevated command prompt (Run as Administrator)

Comment: Thanks, I tried running Git Bash as administrator as well as Win Power Shell as administrator, but I still receive the same error when running vagrant up.

Comment: Are you on Virtualbox 5.0.x? If so make sure you go to the website and download the newest 5.2.x version.

Comment: @joepferguson Thank you so much for your amazing Homestead tool. I wonder if you could clear something up for me (probably really easily): https://stackoverflow.com/q/50535511/470749

Answer (score 0):

Here are some resources explaining how to install Laravel Homestead on Windows

https://www.whenalive.com/laravel-homestead-on-windows-10-with-virtualization-using-vagrant-and-virtualbox-step-by-step-guide/

https://medium.com/@eaimanshoshi/i-am-going-to-write-down-step-by-step-procedure-to-setup-homestead-for-laravel-5-2-17491a423aa