# Laravel Homestead's versions and how it relates to Vagrant, etc

Tags: laravel, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

I love Laravel Homestead and use it every day, but I'm confused about some terminology.

Can someone please explain in basic terms what each of these are and then how they fit together?

- VirtualBox
- Vagrant
- Homestead (and why is this [under the "Laravel" umbrella](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/homestead#introduction)... is it just a recipe that contains everything that Laravel needs?)

I still don't understand why the [latest release number](https://github.com/laravel/homestead/releases/) (currently [v7.6.0](https://github.com/laravel/homestead/releases/tag/v7.6.0)) doesn't match  the latest VirtualBox version of Homestead (currently v6.0.0 at [6.0.0/providers/virtualbox.box](https://vagrantcloud.com/laravel/boxes/homestead/versions/6.0.0/providers/virtualbox.box)).

What do the 2 different numbers refer to?

(I.e. Why would there not be a new `.box` for every new release/tag of Homestead in Github?)

P.S. In case it's relevant, I use Windows 10, which is why I love Homestead, since managing versions of PHP and other dependencies on Windows is a nightmare. Thank you very much, @joepferguson!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good questions but I have a feeling they will be found inappropriate for stack overflow. but seeing as how I crave reputation, heres my answer:

- Virtualbox: this is the hypervisor software running on your system.
  This hosts your VMs and allocates resources (cpu, memory, network
  etc)
- Vagrant: this is software that interacts with your chosen hypervisor
  to swiftly create, start/stop, destroy VMs. It uses a configuration
  file to manage various aspects of the VMs (naming, networking etc).
  Consider this an intermediate between you and your hypervisor that
  simplifies the process of handling VMs.
- Homestead: this is software by the creators of Laravel. It includes a vagrant VM that comes preconfigured with all of the dependencies (php,
  mysql etc) that Laravel needs. Homestead also has some helper functions to map directories on your host system (that runs the hypervisor) to your laravel vagrant VMs,

Homestead release numbers are not tied to the Laravel versions they ship with. They are separate projects in separate github repos.

The vagrant box 'laravel/homestead' similarly has its own versioning.

as to your question 'Why would there not be a new .box for every new release/tag of Homestead in Github?' - I think there might actually be a new release for every laravel release. Bear in mind that laravel/settler was released Feb 2017, so it doesnt have the same history as Laravel...